# Rails 4 - Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`User` has_many `Tickets`.

`Ticket` belongs_to `User` (`ticket.user_id`)

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  resources :tickets
end
```

**rake routes**

```
user_tickets GET /users/:user_id/tickets(.:format) tickets#index
```

**users/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to("View User's Tickets", user_tickets_path(user)) %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @tickets = @user.tickets
end
```

**tickets_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @search = Ticket.search(params[:q])
  @tickets = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
  render 'shared/tickets.html.erb'
end
```

When I hover over link, it shows `.../users/[the selected user's id]/tickets`

When it goes to the ticket/index page, it shows ALL tickets, not just the tickets with the selected user's id.

I'm pretty sure my route is incorrect, or it may be something else entirely.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I think my problem is that I need to call `@tickets` in the tickets_controller/index method a variety of ways, because I want to use that view for `@tickets.all`, `@user.tickets`, `@facility.tickets`, etc (to keep it DRY).

The same index list of tickets needs to change, based on the link from whence it came (whether it comes from the user list, showing a list of all tickets by that user, or from the facility list, showing a list of all tickets by that facility).  I'm just doing something horribly wrong somewhere.

**Possible solution I will try:**

Maybe I need to create custom routes, like `get 'users_tickets' => "users#users_tickets"`, then put the `@tickets` conditions in that method and call the shared/tickets.html.erb that way.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to step through the association. Did you use

**tickets_controller.rb**

```
def index
     @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
     @tickets = @user.tickets
end
```

in the controller? If this doesn't help, can you post the controller code?

Comment: I added my controller code to the original post - I used the new way of `def set_user...`  Is that ok or should it go in the index or...?

Comment: I would think we should be looking at the index method of the tickets_controller.

Comment: Oh!!  That's where I'm going wrong.  Updated post with original tickets_controller, which I will fix now to see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: I use the shared/tickets.html.erb so I can view tickets by user, facility, department, etc... how would I update my tickets controller for shared use?

Comment: Are you sure tickets are being added ONLY to certain users? How are you adding tickets to a user?

Comment: When a user creates a ticket, his id is saved to ticket.user_id (in tickets create method - and I verified the id is being saved correctly in the database)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you trying to whittle down @tickets rather than do another query?

Right now you're redefining @tickets when they hit the tickets index, and it doesn't care that you defined @tickets as just belonging to that user on the users_controller.  It just ignores that because you're using direct assignment in your tickets_controller index action.  You probably want something like:

**tickets_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @search = Ticket.search(params[q])
    @tickets = @search.result.where(user: @user)
    @tickets = @tickets.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
end
```

Not tested, but I think that's more what you're wanting.

Comment: Exactly right.  I'm not sure how to call @tickets index to show the list of tickets with different conditions (by user, by facility, by division, etc) - that's where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I think I need to review nested resources again, because I thought they did what I wanted automatically...or maybe they do, and I just don't get it yet.

In any case, I ended up creating a custom route and custom method in users:

**routes.rb**

```
 get 'user_tickets' => "users#user_tickets"
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def user_tickets
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @search = Ticket.where(:user_id => @user.id).search(params[:q])
    @tickets = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
    render 'shared/tickets.html.erb'
  end
```

then, called:

```
<%= link_to("View Tickets", user_tickets_path(:id => user.id)) %>
```

I will do the same for facilities, departments, etc.  Not sure this is the best way, but it works.

Thanks everyone for stimulating my brain cells.